# Как вывести массив json полученный в ответе ajax в таблицу

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp

Не могу заполнить таблицу данными которые приходят от сервлета с помощью ajax.
Ситуация такая, при нажатии на объект в таблице я отправляю его в сервлет, там запрос выбирает мне данные с таблицы в БД, и отправляет ответ на страницу. Не знаю как правильно организовать цикл для вывода данных табличку.

Объект с данными:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Jsp:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="classInfo" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-body">
                <table id="tableListModal" class="table table-striped table-bordered" acceptCharset="UTF-8">
                    <thead id="backgroundSearchHead">
                        <tr>
                            <th rowspan="2">Термін впровадження</th>
                            <th colspan="4">Металолом</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Цех</th>
                            <th>Чор-<br>мет.</th>
                            <th>Кол.<br>мет.</th>
                            <th>Норма<br>витрати<br>матеріалу<br>на<br>заготовку</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="valueSvi"></td>
                            <td class="valueNcm"></td>
                            <td class="valueVmch"></td>
                            <td class="valueKmcv"></td>
                            <td class="valueNrmzmc"></td>                                        
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <button type="button" class="btn  pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">
                    Закрити
                </button>
            </div>     
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>

        $(document).ready(function () {

            // code to read selected table row cell data (values).
            $("#tableList").on('click', '.takeTd', function () {
                // get the current row
                var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
                var col = currentRow.find(".takeOsd").text();
                var trimCol = $.trim(col);
                var osdObj = {
                    "osdAj": trimCol
                };
                $.ajax({
                    url: "modalOsdSpnrm",
                    method: "post",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: osdObj,
                    error: function (message) {
                        // console.log(message);
                    },
                    success: function (data) {                        
                         console.log(data[0]);

                         $('.valueSvi').text(data[0].svi);
                         $('.valueNcm').text(data[0].ncm);
                         $('.valueVmch').text(data[0].vmch);
                         $('.valueKmcv').text(data[0].kmcv);
                         $('.valueNrmzmc').text(data[0].nrmzmc);                         
                    }
                });
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: не плохо бы увидеть объект с данными

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Дополнил вопрос.

Comment: html с таблицей  предоставьте

Comment: @doox911 дополнил

Comment: Должно работать, а что за ошибка? Или что в консоле в ответе?

Comment: @doox911 Работает только если в ответе одна строка, когда их как на скриншоте команда `console.log(data[0]);` ничего не выводит, и показывает пустую таблицу, хотя с сервлета эти данные летят на jsp без ошибок(

Comment: @doox911 Вот такое консоль пишет когда в объекте всего одна запись - `{svi: "2000-01-01", ncm: "  0", vmch: "", kmcv: "", nrmzmc: "0.0000000"}`

Comment: `let res = JSON.parse(data);` и потом пробуйте вывести (вместо `data` используйте `res`)

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Вот такое пишет "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1" Да и я в json преобразовываю в самом сервлете, поэтому не факт что и на странице нужно.

Comment: он не может распарсить json ваш..проверьте его на правильность...выведите не data[0], а data полностью в консоль (при наличии многих записей) и покажите сюда

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц вы правы) Где-то ошибка в `json`

Comment: ошиька в том, что названия должны быть обрамлены в ковычки.. так `{
 "svi": "2000-01-01",
 "ncm": " 0",
 "vmch": "",
 "kmcv": "",
 "nrmzmc": "0.0000000"
}`. Попытайтесь разобраться почему ваш клиент получает "кривой" JSON

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц написал просто data и оно не выводит ничего там где много записей, только где одна(

Comment: инспектор -> network -> найдите ваш запрос и сделайте скрин что уходит, что приходит. Дайте код функции сервера, когда он отдает значение (желательно в дебаге, чтобы знать что именно)

Comment: странно в Java в объекте оно так и есть, названия в кавычках, а вот в браузере нет

Comment: посмотрите значение при `return`... и тип...возможно это как то влияет на переформирования значений. Вы прям `searchList` и возвращаете, или что-то еще делаете потом? а то скрин у вас не понятный

Comment: Возвращаю и все, дальше уже все в скрипте.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94630/discussion-between---and-sorpok).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была связана со стороною на сервере. Данные отдавались в цикле, поэтому на клиент приходила "каша"